# Как очистить ключ от пробелов в meta_query?

Tags: wordpress

Есть запрос

```
$recent2 = new WP_Query(
array(
  'orderby' => '',
  'showposts'=>-1,
  'meta_query' => array( 
    array(
      'key' => 'cena',
      'value' => array(2500, 2999), // matches exactly "red"
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )));
```

Все работает если цена стоит 2500. Но некоторые пользователи добавили цену с пробелом(2 500).
Как сделать что фильтровалось верно. Или как массово подвести все цены к 1 виду.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте preg_replace:

```
$price = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $price );
```

Comment: И где мне его использовать? Этот запрос как фильтр вытягивает все записи попадающие в диапазон.  Проблема в том что кастомное поле под цену задано как текст, а не как число. Потому пользователи могут добавлять цену с пробелом. Если я сейчас изменю тип поля то все заполненные поля пропадут.

Comment: У вас данные в БД? Напишите тогда скрипт удалите пробелы, например через preg_replace. И замените поле на число

Comment: В базе данных удалил в поле Cena пробелы. И изменил тип данных этого поля на Число